# Using AND vs && in a for loop (Not related to precedence?)

Tags: php, logical-operators

Why is it that this code prints "Hello!" four times and then prints "1":

```
<?php
for ($i=1 AND $blah=1; $i<5; $i++) echo("Hello!");
echo($blah);
?>
```

While this doesn't print out "Hello!" at all and then prints "1":

```
<?php
for ($i=1 && $blah=1; $i<5; $i++) echo("Hello!");
echo($blah);
?>
```

I know AND and && have different precedences, but that doesn't seem to apply here. What am I missing?
(I'm using a variant of the code above, since I will use $blah within the for loop, and I want to set the value for it).
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@OP, please read [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) doc. It explains the difference under Example #1 logical operators

Comment: This is a link-only answer. Please post the bulk of your message in the answer itself, rather than pointing to an offsite resource.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that either the AND or && are what you're looking for here.  If you want to execute both `$i=1` and `$blah=1` in the initialization expression, you need to separate them with a comma:

```
for ($i=1, $blah=1; $i<5; $i++) echo("Hello!");
```